# List of Tables Are Separated by File

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, tocloft

I am generating a list of tables. My tables are in different files (tables in chapter1.tex) (table chapter2.tex)....

I have been going at it for a while now trying to fix it. I have noticed that the blank line happens if tables are in sperate files. Also, I am using Overleaf.
[image]

I am talking about the space between Table 2, Table 3 and Table 3, Table 4. How do I fix this?

Main file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage[margin=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{romanbar}
%================================================================
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
%================================================================
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Exported_Items.bib}

%================================================================
\usepackage[skip=5pt,font=small]{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=endash}
\captionsetup[figure]{name={Figure},labelsep=endash}
%================================================================
%\geometry{a4paper,left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm}
\setstretch{1.15}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
%\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%================================================================
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%

}

%================================================================
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont\bfseries\centering}{CHAPTER \
\thechapter}{0em}{}

\titleformat{\section}
{\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont\bf}
{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\fontsize{13}{18.2}\bf}
{\thesubsection.}{0.5em}{}

\titlespacing{\section}{0in}{12pt}{8pt}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0in}{12pt}{8pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0in}{12pt}{8pt}


%================================================================
\newcommand{\fontfourteen}[1]{\fontsize{14}{19.6}\selectfont #1}
\newcommand{\adname}{Adélie}
\newcommand{\toolname}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand{\centeredt}[1]{\begin{tabular}{l} #1 \end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\nth}{\textsuperscript{th}\xspace}

%================================================================
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand*\listfigurename {LIST OF FiGURES}
\renewcommand*\listtablename{LIST OF  TABLES}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{.}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{.}}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER } % CHAPTER before number in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{23mm}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont\bfseries}
%================================================================
\renewcommand{\cftfigdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{FIGURE }
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{18mm}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{ -}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont}
%=================================================================
\renewcommand{\cfttabdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{TABLE }
\renewcommand{\cfttabnumwidth}{18mm}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{ -}
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{\fontsize{10}{14}\selectfont}




\begin{document}

%================================================================


\include{title/title}
\include{title/blank_page}
\include{title/Ethical_Statment}
\include{title/blank_page}
\include{title/Super_cert}
\include{title/blank_page}
\include{title/dedications}
\include{title/symbols_abbrv}
\include{title/Abstract}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{5pt}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
\end{center}
\begin{center}

    \listoffigures
    \clearpage
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{0pt}
    \listoftables
\end{center}


\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
\include{Chapter3}



\printbibliography[title={REFERENCES}]

\include{Appendicies}


\end{document}
```

Here is what is inside Chapter1.tex

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter[INTRODUCTION]{\centering INTRODUCTION}
\begin{table}[]
\caption{f}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\hline
 aa&         b  &        c  & d &  e\\ \hline

\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[]
\caption{y}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\hline
 aa&         b  &        c  & d &  e\\ \hline

\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: That's not necessarily related to the tables being included in separated files but more likely due to them being in separate chapters.

Comment: @leandriis Tested that, added a chapter before Table 2, which is in the same file as Table 1. The issue remains.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69327/134144 might be interesting.

Comment: Also, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448891/reducing-the-space-between-the-items-of-list-of-figures-and-list-of-tables

Comment: The solution by Gonzalo Medina [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69321/spacing-between-chapters-in-list-of-tables/69327#69327) solved this issue.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you.